# Specify more than one argument to grep -v

Tags: unix, command-line, find

How do I supply more than one string to ignore to grep's -v flag?

eg I want to ignore results from files names error_log and baz?

`find /home/foo/bar.com/ -mmin -12 | grep -v error_log baz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /home/foo/bar.com/ -mmin -12 | grep -v 'error_log\|baz'
```

Comment: Thank you! One of my security cron jobs was sending me ten notices an hour on automated files of no concern.  Much obliged for the help!